# Trying to spawn bubbles that do not overlap. Why doesn't this work?

Tags: java, processing

```
ArrayList<Bubble> bubbles = new ArrayList<Bubble>();

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  background(210);

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

    Bubble bubble = new Bubble();

    for (Bubble b : bubbles) {

      float d = dist(b.pos.x, b.pos.y, bubble.pos.x, bubble.pos.y);

      while (d < 40) { // which means 2 * r (radius of bubble)
        bubble.ChangePos();
        d = dist(b.pos.x, b.pos.y, bubble.pos.x, bubble.pos.y);
      }
    }

    bubbles.add(bubble);
  }

  for (Bubble b : bubbles) {
    fill(255, 0, 90, 50);
    b.Display();
  }
}

class Bubble {

  PVector pos = new PVector(random(width), random(height));
  float r = 20;

  void Display() {
    ellipse(pos.x, pos.y, r * 2, r * 2);
  }

  void ChangePos() {
    pos.set(random(width), random(height));
  }
}
```

I'm trying to make that if a bubble is overlapping another bubble it's position changes until it isn't overlapping a bubble - so while the distance between one new bubble that im creating and the existing bubbles in the bubbles array, the new bubble's position changes.

Comment: Can you describe what's wrong with what you did?

Comment: bubbles are spawning on each other :(

Comment: I guess it's the set(random(width), random(height)) that's causing the problem. Lets say you compared 2 bubbles and the position changed to avoid overlapping. When you compare it with another bubble, the random function may again set the possition of bubble to overlap with the one's you compared before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you create a bubble. It's the only bubble, so it can't overlap any other bubbles. So far so good. Then you create another bubble, and it's not overlapping the first one, so you're still okay.

Then you create a third bubble. Now you loop through the first two bubbles, and you find that it's not overlapping the first bubble, but it is overlapping the second bubble. So you assign it a random position until it's not overlapping the second bubble anymore. **But you don't check whether it's overlapping the first bubble again.** So you could move the third bubble to be on top of the first bubble.

Apply that logic to 100 bubbles, and it's pretty likely that you'll have overlapping circles.

To fix this problem, you're going to have to recheck against every single bubble every time you change the position. This is going to become extremely slow at some point. There are smarter ways to do it, so you might want to look into [circle packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing) algorithms.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! great explanation :)